# Will Torchlight II allow importing characters from Torchlight I?

Tags: torchlight-2, torchlight

Torchlight II is out, but so far I could not find any information if it will allow me to import my character from the first game.

Does anyone have better knowledge?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since Torchlight II will have completely new character classes, and none of the ones from Torchlight I will have a comingback, you will not be able to use old characters.

It is also stated in [Torchlight II FAQ](http://forums.runicgames.com/viewtopic.php?f=30&t=14139) in Runic Games official Forum:

> **Will I be able to import my old characters?**
> No, the original characters will be in the game as NPCs, as will other NPCs of the Destroyer, Vanquisher, and Alchemist class types. Additionally, due to various changes in gamplay systems the old character files will not be able to be imported as-is, as detailed below:
>
> Along with the story the game will use a new wardrobing system opposed to the one in Torchlight. As a result they did not reuse the Torchlight character assets.

Comment: Good point about character class, but they can always "convert" to the closest class if they really want. :/